# QML map proper markers instantiating

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qml, openstreetmap

I have a map (OpenStreetMaps) displayed using Map.qml ( Window { ... Map {...} } )
I have a Marker.qml file (based on MapQuickItem). All is OK, when I place this marker statically to my map: Map { ... Marker { params } }.

I want to place N markers (that, sure, have coords and other params). Markers params defined in somefile.txt and this file is parsed using C++.

The question is how to proper/faster/correctly instantiate and place parsed points to Map? Should I do method in Map.qml like a addMarker(position, name) { map.addMapItem( ? ) }?
Or should I place this marker using only C++, like get Map container and invoke addMapItem on some "map-projected" class?

Please, help me to understand pipeline of this.

Comment: Ok, if you parse your data in C++ so it would be logical to instance items in C++ too. And this way is the fastest one I guess.

Comment: As now I investigated, that I can't interact with map from C++ (qt documentation said this). Now I'm trying to invoke addMarker(name, position) from c++, and then QML creates object and placec on map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `MapItemView`.

Your C++ code would provide the marker info (location, name, etc) via a model which is then used as input to the `MapItemView`.
The view then creates a map view item for each entry in the model and places it on its parent map.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-places-qml.html#display-search-results-using-a-mapitemview for an example.

Your C++ code can modify the model during runtime in anyway it sees fit, e.g. adding or removing entries, modifying data of entries.

Comment: So I should place everything (instantiate Marker.qml to object and add to parent map) using QML. C++ code therefore will invoke (using QMetaObject::invokeMethod) addMarker QML method etc. Right?

Comment: Not quite. Yes, you would handle the markers in QML, but you don't call anything from C++.
The C++ part of your application provides the data you need for your markers, e.g. coordinates, names, etc.
One way to do that is a model, e.g. a custom class derived from `QAbstractItemModel`. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html for the general concept. The only difference for you is that you are using a `MapItemView` instead of a `ListView`

Comment: Yes, ok, I will try today. But, if my fix is dynamic, I should make static fixes list and dynamic fixes list that will be updated. As I read I need to emit dataChanged so QML will get new data. Right?

Comment: `dataChanged()` needs to be emitted when the data of an already existing entry changes. If you add entries  you call `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()`, similar functions for when removing entries.
Not sure what you mean with static and dynamic, but a model can of course keep any portion of its data unchanged if it wants to